# Modern Page Likes - REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, rating, like

On a SharePoint Modern site, at the bottom of each page there is a small footer that contains the Like button and number of views.

Where does this like count go though?

It is not stored in the classic `LikesCount` column as I expected and I cannot find any documentation on it anywhere.

Can this data even be retrieved by the REST API?

Comment: I have found that there is a hidden column called "_likeCount" that holds the value - however I cannot seem to access using the REST API still

Answer (score 2):

The likes count is stored in a separate data store.

You can access it via REST API.

To access the likes count of a modern page, you can use the below endpoint:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/GetItemById(<ID>)/
likedByInformation?$expand=likedby&$top=10
```

The result will give you `likeCount` as below. Please do its not quite well documented :

[image]

For comments information, you can refer to [Vardhman Deshpande's excellent blog post](https://www.vrdmn.com/2017/07/working-with-page-comments-rest-api-in.html)

Documentation - [Microsoft.SharePoint.Likes.likedByInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt848434(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Is this possible to get the like count for list items or is the only way to do another call per item?

Comment: if you want it for all pages, you can use it as `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/items?$expand=likedByInformation`

Comment: doing that only returns the number of likes from the rating column not the new modern count - which is where my problem is

Comment: ohhh, in that case would suggest that you make a REST API call for each page list item as i mentioned in the answer. This is a bummer :(